# Wordpress нужна консультация. Какой плагин выбрать, для определённых работ?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть сайт, хочу сделать скидку на первый товар в размере 20%. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать. Я сильно сомневаюсь,  что это возможно без регистрации сделать, ведь нам нужно как-то идентифицировать пользователя, верно?

Если я прав, то какой плагин для этого лучше всего выбрать? Как сделать так, что-бы давалась скидка на первый заказ. Естественно человеку ещё должно писаться на странице оплате, что у вас будет скидка.

Я прошу не писать что-то по типу "Создай промокод и не морочь себе голову", для меня это не подходит, мне нужно что-бы сайт сам давал скидку, если первый заказ.

Видел например вот этот сайт https://inbenefit.com/woocommerce-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/

Я скачал от сюда второй плагин "Ultimate Membership (WooCommerce)", с ним получится это сделать? Если нет, то какой тогда плагин выбрать.

Comment: Не нужно задавать такие вопросы. Правильного ответа нет т.к. если я вам скажу, что берите этот плагин - это сугубо мое субъективное мнение. Данный вопрос не поможет никак других пользователям

Comment: Причем тут конкретно этот плагин? Может быть кто-то уже такое делал, я спрашиваю их. Если не можете дать ответа, не пишите.